# Custom view not getting initialised

Tags: ios, swift

I have a custom view for radio buttons included in my project. I have made a connection from that view in storyboard to my outlet in the view controller.

When I try to access that outlet to set the delegate in view did load, the app crashes (doesn't show any error on the console). I tried to set the delegate of that object to test as I was getting a EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x000..) error on trying to set one of its properties. When I try to print description of the object, it doesn't recognise it as an object of the custom class I am setting it to, but just a UIView. I have no code that access the outlet in the view controller or any other view controller.

I have tried reconnecting the outlet but that wouldn't be the issue as it works fine on testing scheme of the app. The app crashes on the App Store scheme of the app.

**Note:** -

1. Since I am not that familiar with what all details of the scheme might bring in this sort of unexpected behaviour (if at all any), and how to share the details of such behaviour, please let me know the extra details that might be relevant to debugging this issue in the comments and I will update the question with the details.
2. Also note that I have included the custom view class to the app store target (so that's not the issue).

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

**Update**

1. Code assigning delegate is done is `viewDidLoad()`

   customView.delegate = self
2. There are two init for custom class (I didn't write it so don't know exactly why)

   ```
   required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
       super.init(coder: aDecoder)
       initializeSubviews()
   }

   override init(frame: CGRect) {
       super.init(frame: frame)
       initializeSubviews()
   }

   func initializeSubviews() {
       let xibFileName = "xibName"
       let view = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType).loadNibNamed(xibFileName, owner: self, options: nil)![0] as! UIView
       view.tag = 1111
       self.addSubview(view)
       view.frame = self.bounds

       radio1Img.hidden = true

       let radio1ImgTappedG: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(RadioButton2.radio1ImgTapped))
       radio1Img.addGestureRecognizer(radio1ImgTappedG)

       let radio1CaptionTappedG: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(RadioButton2.radio1CaptionTapped))
       radio1Caption.addGestureRecognizer(radio1CaptionTappedG)

       let radio2ImgTappedG: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(RadioButton2.radio2ImgTapped))
       radio2Img.addGestureRecognizer(radio2ImgTappedG)

       let radio2CaptionTappedG: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(RadioButton2.radio2CaptionTapped))
       radio2Caption.addGestureRecognizer(radio2CaptionTappedG)

       let radio3ImgTappedG: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(RadioButton2.radio3ImgTapped))
       radio3Img.addGestureRecognizer(radio3ImgTappedG)

       let radio3CaptionTappedG: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(RadioButton2.radio3CaptionTapped))
       radio3Caption.addGestureRecognizer(radio3CaptionTappedG)

       let radio4ImgTappedG: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(RadioButton2.radio4ImgTapped))
       radio4Img.addGestureRecognizer(radio4ImgTappedG)

       let radio4CaptionTappedG: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(RadioButton2.radio4CaptionTapped))
       radio4Caption.addGestureRecognizer(radio4CaptionTappedG)


       radio1Caption.hidden = true
       radio1Caption.textColor = UIColor(netHex: 0x8C8C8C)
       radio2Img.hidden = true
       radio2Caption.hidden = true
       radio2Caption.textColor = UIColor(netHex: 0x8C8C8C)
       radio3Img.hidden = true
       radio3Caption.hidden = true
       radio3Caption.textColor = UIColor(netHex: 0x8C8C8C)
       radio4Img.hidden = true
       radio4Caption.hidden = true
       radio4Caption.textColor = UIColor(netHex: 0x8C8C8C)
   }
   ```

Also note that I have a very similar custom view with almost the same code but different UI, and that view works without any problems.

**Update:** Adding image of the crash logs from the device.
[image: 1], [image: 2], [image: 3]

Comment: Please add some code of how you are assigning the delegate to Outlet.

Comment: could you provide the init code for your custom class

Comment: @KAR I have updated the question to include code.

Comment: @Rishabh I have updated the question to include code.

Comment: 1. Make sure the outlet is connected to the correct property.
2. Make sure the connected properties from outlets has existed.

Comment: @TonyTran I've tried reconnecting the outlet. Also the same code works perfectly in another target

Comment: I think you should add the screenshot of the crash log.

Comment: @Skywalker Hey, just curious, you've used `delegate` but how did you support with your custom controller. Did you use a `protocol` for custom class to using `delegate` ?

Comment: @elia Yes. I have a protocol defined. But it is not relevant for this view controller. I do not need it here. I just set the delegate in `viewDidLoad` to test if it is getting altered somewhere else.

Comment: @Skywalker Are you getting this error on simulator?

Comment: @KAR Yes. Both on simulator and device.

Comment: If another target works, so it should be related to target issue. You can try to clean the project, delete derived data, re-assign the class for the xib file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I forgot to update this question with an answer once I got the answer.

So I solved the issue. It seems to be a target related issue. The view for the outlet in the storyboard belonged to a different module.

[image]

In the identity inspector, the module was selected as the enterprise module. So it did not get included in the app store build. When I set the module as empty, the app worked fine for both the schemes.

I don't know how to explain it better. If someone can shed light on this by explaining more, it would be well appreciated.

Anyways, this is what finally worked.